# Why C++ non-static data members require unique addresses?

Tags: attributes, c++20, datamember

Recently C++ has added the feature `[[no_unique_address]]` for empty data types such as `struct empty {};`.

How do empty data memberes benefit from having a unique address?

Why wouldn't the standard make all empty data members address-less?

Why C++ non-static data members require unique addresses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because (among other things), that's how C does it. If C++ was to be able to be layout-compatible with C, then an empty NSDM of a C++ struct would have to take up the same space as an equivalent C declaration.

Empty base class optimization was able to be added to C++ because base classes aren't C language features, so there was never any question about compatibility with C. If you want to allow empty member optimization, you have to have the C++ programmer be *explicit* about whether they want to make the optimization available (and therefore, the type isn't directly compatible to a C type). You can't just spring it on them.

Comment: I don't think C allows empty structs.

Comment: @T.C.: [Seems to compile just fine](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/4q59Lg)